# Django models, ¿Cómo requerir marcar checkbox para permitir el envio de formulario?

Tags: django-models

Necesito crear un formulario de contacto que solo pueda ser enviado si el usuario da su consentimiento haciendo click en la casilla Agree. Estoy usando Models ya que necesito que todos los datos, incluido el consentimiento, queden guardados en la base de datos. He intentado usar Required pero en Booleanfield de Models no es válido.
Se agradece de antemano su ayuda.

Models.py [Agrego función Clean]

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="Prenom")
    surname=models.CharField(max_length=30,verbose_name="Nom")
    mail=models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email")
    telephone=models.CharField(verbose_name="Téléphone",max_length=13)
    message=models.TextField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Message")
    agree=models.BooleanField(verbose_name="J'accepte d'être contacté")
    
    def clean(self):
        if self.agree==False:
            raise ValidationError("aprobar")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Forms.py

```
class contactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model=Contact
        fields='__all__'
```

Views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request,"home.html")
def services(request):
    return render(request,"services.html")
def contact(request):
    return render(request,"contact.html")


def contact(request):
    data={
        'form': contactForm()
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formu=contactForm(data=request.POST)
        if formu.is_valid:
            formu.save()
            data["message"]="Merci beaucoup pour votre message, nous vous contacterons très prochainement."
        else:
            data["form"]=formu


    return render(request,'contact.html',data)
```

Contact.html

```
{% extends "VaporApp/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<h2>Nous contacter</h2>
<form action=""class="formulario_contacto" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    <br>
    <button type="submit" id="btnEnviar" class="button">Envoyer</button>

</form>
{{message}}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que un booleano no tiene required, de hecho por defecto debería grabar false.

Donde se valida si un campo es requerido o no es en el formulario, se puede validar también en la vista pero por seguridad deberás validarlo en backed, para ello busca en la documentación hay varias formas:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/

por tanto, un ejemplo de tu formulario (veo que no has indicado el código del formulario), seria:

```
class contactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField()
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    recipients = MultiEmailField()
    agree = forms.BooleanField(required=True)
```

Como vemos, el último campo indica que es requerido, entonces fallará en is_valid(), podremos incluso manejar en la clase del formulario la validación para indicar el error a la vista que deseemos.

Si no queremos cambiar los campos como en este caso, otra forma es preparar la opción clean_agree para nuestro formulario:

```
def clean_agree(self):
   agree = self.cleaned_data.get('agree')
   if not agree:
      raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required')
   return agree
```

De esta forma podemos validar que no se inserte si el campo no es correcto.

Otra tercera opción sería crear un validador custom en el modelo:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/custom-field-validations-in-django-models/

No sé si esta última te interesa más, hay más formas de realizarlo, incluso te diría que en la propia vista si quieres que sea requerido, no dejes avanzar si no está marcado, aunque siempre tendrás que validarlo en el servidor, porque en la vista se puede hacer trampa.

Comment: He agregado el forms y el html que no había detallado antes. El formulario esta hecho con la clase Modelform, tomando el modelo que ya definí en models, y el problema que encuentro es que no se puede poner required dentro del BooleanField.

Comment: otra opción es usar el método clean_ del formulario, si quieres indicar __all__ para los campos, modifico la respuesta

Comment: He agregado la función clean en Model.py (modifico en mi publicación original) y la validación funciona pero solo cuando relleno el formulario desde el Admin, al hacerlo desde contacto me sale error ValueError at /contact
The Contact could not be created because the data didn't validate .

Comment: ya lo he solucionado, en Views.py me faltaban los () en if formu.is_valid: gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: puntuándome positivamente me doy por agradecido ;) jeje